# Pronunciation of "отпуска"

Tags: произношение

How am I supposed to pronounce **отпуска**?

I've seen both *о́тпуска* and *отпуска́*. My dictionary is kinda ambiguous so I'm struggling with this one.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA), which is already mentioned by @Eugene, could be a useful tool in such cases. Many words have their inflections documented with stress marks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Óтпуска* is the **Genitive** case **singular** of *óтпуск*:

> У меня давно не было óтпуска. – I haven't got a vacation for a long time.

*Отпускá* is the **Nominative** and **Accusative** case **plural** of *óтпуск*:

> Друзья рассказали мне, как они провели свои отпускá. – My friends told me how they had spent their vacations.

Comment: I wonder if the latter is a somewhat vulgar/dialectic form, as I think the formally normal plural should be "óтпуски"

Comment: @Arioch check here: [Викисловарь: "отпуск"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA) or [Грамота.ру:"отпуск"](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA&all=x)

Comment: BTW, this is not unique to **отпуска**. Quite a few Russian words only have stress to differentiate their grammatical forms: **поезда, страны, волос**  Some words can be stressed in three different ways: **округа, перепела, выносим.** Those are quite rare.